# Trying to read a big file of 500,000 lines and store it in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, java.util.scanner, readfile

which checks the performance of different sorting algorithms. We were given a .txt file with 500,000 words, which are going to be sorted with these algorithms. I wrote the method that reads the file and stores the words in a String array. The first `Scanner` counts the number of lines and the second `Scanner` creates the array using the counter but it only works with files with much less lines. Ican't really share the content of the text file, it is just a file containing 1 word in each line.

When I try to read the file with the 500,000 lines I get this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
> at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
> at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
> at Tester.readArray(Tester.java:81)
> at Tester.main(Tester.java:7)

Do you think it is because my computer does not support it, or do I need to change the method?
Here is my method:

```java
public static String[] readArray(String file) {
    int wordCounter = 0;
    try {
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new File(file));
        while (s1.hasNextLine()) {
            wordCounter = wordCounter + 1;
            s1.next();
        }
        s1.close();
        String[]words = new String[wordCounter];
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(new File(file));
        for (int i = 0; i < wordCounter; i = i + 1) {
            words[i] = s2.next();
        }
        return words;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your computer or anything, but a bug in your code.  I suspect it has to do with the distinction between `hasNextLine()` and `next()` instead of e.g. `hasNext()` or `nextLine()`.  I recommend testing it on a file with, say, two lines.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post a sample of the contents of the text file?

Comment: Also, you are swallowing the `FileNotFoundException` if it's thrown.

Comment: Don't use `next()`, use `nextLine()` to read a line. Aside, why do you read the file twice? Use an `ArrayList` and `add()` each line to it. Then convert the list to an array if needed.

Comment: @Abra HI! it is just a file with with 500,000 lines, and each line contains only one word.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I'm not so pro yet, I didn't know ArrayList and add(), but I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: @MaggieRIv `java.util.ArrayList` is a variable-capacity, array-backed implementation of the `java.util.List` interface. When you `add` an element to an `ArrayList` and its backing array is too small, it will actually resize the array to accommodate more elements. That way you don't have to do two passes over the file. And since `ArrayList` is backed by an array, it remains random access (i.e., O(1) access time complexity). If you need to, you can convert the list to an array via `theList.toArray(String[]::new)` (or `theList.toArray(new String[0])` on older versions of Java).

Comment: And note that `List` (and, by extension, `ArrayList`) is generic. So, you'll want to parameterize it as `List<String>` / `ArrayList<String>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for me replacing `hasNextLine()` with `hasNext()` fixed the exception. This has nothing to do with your PC.
I think this error can occur, when you have an empty line at the end of your file. Because, when I removed my empty line at the end of the file i was reading the exception was not thrown.

Comment: I think it work! it's still running tho, it hasn't given me an answer, I guess it takes a while due to the amount of lines maybe?

Comment: @MaggieRIv Reading 500,000 lines, where each line is a legitimate word (meaning they won't be long), should take almost no time at all. And a 500,000-element array is not a large array (by "real world" standards, anyway). So, sorting shouldn't take too long either. Though your performance-measuring code may still take a while depending on how its implemented (e.g., repeating tests, reading the file every time instead of just copying the array per sort, etc.). But if you find your program is taking an abnormally long time, I'd make sure you aren't getting stuck in an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: @Slaw damn in that case I think I'm getting stuck. It works with files under 100,000 lines tho

Comment: @MaggieRIv You can place print statements at strategic locations in your code to see if that code is being reached (if not, then you're getting stuck before it). Or if you know how to use a debugger, you can use breakpoints to do the same. Also, make sure you aren't swallowing exceptions (like you do to the `FileNotFoundException` in the code in your question). At the very least call `printStackTrace()` on them so you know an error occurred (along with what the error is and where it was thrown).

Comment: @MaggieRIv On my computer, using your two-pass `Scanner` approach could take anywhere between 600-1000ms (500,000 lines). That's not a terribly long time. Though note I used `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()`, only counting/including non-blank lines. Changing it to a one-pass `Scanner` solution cut the time approximately in half (predictably). But using a `BufferedReader` (and its `readLine()` method) instead of `Scanner` dropped the time to approximately 120ms. Much faster. My guess as to why `Scanner` is slower is because it's based on regex, whereas `BufferedReader` just looks at the chars.

Comment: @Slaw I printed the array, the readFile method works just find, also the copyArray method, so there is a problem while sorting because the result doesn,'t print.  Your tip helped me ty.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner‘s hasNextLine() method checks if there is another line in the input, no matter if the line is blank or not, while hasNext() uses a delimiter to check for another token. using hasNext() might solve your problem. check this for more info [hasNext() vs hasNextLine()](https://www.baeldung.com/java-scanner-hasnext-vs-hasnextline)

However, you are using Scanner class's nextLine() to get the total number of lines. This can be efficient for small to medium-sized files, but may not be suitable for very large files that cannot fit into memory.

```
public static long countLines(String file) {
try {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(file)).parallel().count();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return -1;
}
```

}

This method uses the parallel() method to create a parallel stream of lines, which can improve performance for large files by using multiple threads to process the lines in parallel.